# ruby pass an array to google javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

In my view I have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_time" data-google="<%= @google_array %>"></div>
```

`@google_array` correctly gives an array of arrays (checked in browser console)

I am trying to pass the array to a Google chart js file

```
// var dataView = document.getElementById('chart_time');
let dataView = document.querySelector('#chart_time');
let dataGoogle = dataView.getAttribute('data-google')
data.addRows(dataGoogle);
```

But in the browser I get `Error: Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array`

Comment: Did you tried to parse it? `data.addRows(JSON.parse(dataGoogle));` What is an output of `console.log(dataGoogle)` after you get it from data attribute?

Comment: If you put this as an answer I can approve it - It works beautifully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should parse it:

```
data.addRows(JSON.parse(dataGoogle));
```